# Model Storage process for showing in APS viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm currently working on showing the local model in APS viewer and have a few questions:

1. Is it feasible to store the model in the user's S3 bucket and use the Bucket ID and Object ID from there
2. Assuming the model can be saved in the user's S3 bucket, where are the SVF model details stored after the translation process?
3. If a user utilizes an S3 bucket, does the model get uploaded to the Autodesk cloud or the user's bucket after translation?
4. Is it possible to showcase the model in the APS viewer entirely offline?

Looking forward for some suggestion and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your users' design data wherever you want. However, if you want to translate designs using the Model Derivative service, the design files will need to be stored in our Data Management bucket at least for the duration of the translation. The outputs of the conversion are then stored by the Model Derivative service. If the output format you chose is SVF, you can download the SVF data, and serve it yourself. This can also be used to provide an offline experience.

Comment: Thank you for your response Petr. It helped me in getting more clarity.